# How to query data out of the box using Spring data JPA by both Sort and Pageable?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying [Spring data JPA](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/jpa) in my project. I want to know if there is an out-of-the-box API to query data, by both `Sort` and `Pageable`. Of course, I know I can write that method myself, I just want to know if there is an out-of-the-box one. My DAO extends `JpaRepository`, and I found there are the following methods I can invoke:

```
findAll();
findAll(Pageable pageable);
findAll(Sort sort);
```

But there is no such method as `findAll(Sort sort, Pageable pageable)`, so I am curious.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this:

```
final PageRequest page1 = new PageRequest(
  0, 20, Direction.ASC, "lastName", "salary"
);

final PageRequest page2 = new PageRequest(
  0, 20, new Sort(
    new Order(Direction.ASC, "lastName"), 
    new Order(Direction.DESC, "salary")
  )
);

dao.findAll(page1);
```

As you can see the second form is more flexible as it allows to define different direction for every property (`lastName ASC, salary DESC`).

Comment: Passing multiple columns sorting data from Javascript through a REST controlle can be done with the following Javascript data: ['name,asc', 'location,desc']

Comment: Thanks for your answer and it helped me! Could you please change Order to Sort? It is Sort in Spring data.

Comment: This was my solution however in spring it is: Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(0, 20, new Sort(new Sort.Order(Direction.ASC, "name"), new Sort.Order(Direction.DESC, "salary")));

Comment: Is NUMBER datatype (integer as JPA entity type) allowed as a sort element? My DB has NUMBER data stored and those are primary identifiers for records, can I store by that column with JPA pagable support?

Comment: @Ketan Do you find any solution for this? because I'm trying to get sorted a number but I can't find a solution

Answer (score 15):

Pageable has an option to specify sort as well. From the [java doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html)

```
PageRequest(int page, int size, Sort.Direction direction, String... properties)
```

Creates a new PageRequest with sort parameters applied.

Comment: This way you're setting one sort direction for all properties. If you want to differentiate sort direction per property, you have to use Sort object as Tomasz pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

in 2020, the accepted answer is kinda out of date since the `PageRequest` is deprecated, so you should use code like this :

```
Pageable page = PageRequest.of(pageable.getPageNumber(), pageable.getPageSize(), Sort.by("id").descending());
return repository.findAll(page);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Spring Pageable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html) has a Sort included. So if your request has the values it will return a sorted pageable.

request: 
`domain.com/endpoint?sort=[FIELDTOSORTBY]&[FIELDTOSORTBY].dir=[ASC|DESC]&page=0&size=20`

That should return a sorted pageable by field provided in the provided order.

Comment: I am looking for a similar way and I can sort using the field but I am not able to get the response in the ordered form using asc or desc. How can set the order in request param?

Comment: For example http://localhost:8080/api/endpoint?page=0&size=10&sort=name. Here how can I specify the order i.e asc/desc?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, to use `Pageable` and `Sorting` at the same time I used like below. In this case I took all elements using pagination and sorting by `id` by descending order:

```
modelRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(page, 10, Sort.by("id").descending()))
```

Like above based on your requirements you can sort data with 2 columns as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to provide sort parameter & sort direction right in the URL of the request.
Spring Pageable automatically parses the URL parameters & creates Pageable object that is obtained by your rest controller. I believe it's one of the best solutions since it helps to avoid manual PageRequest/Pageable objects instantiation (notice the comma character before sort direction):

> domain.com/endpoint?sort=[FIELD],[asc|desc]&page=3&size=100

*P.S.*
Other example of sort direction usage described in [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.0.0.M1/reference/html/paging-chapter.html) not works for me (might be outdated).

Answer (score -1):

```
 public List<Model> getAllData(Pageable pageable){
       List<Model> models= new ArrayList<>();
       modelRepository.findAllByOrderByIdDesc(pageable).forEach(models::add);
       return models;
   }
```

Comment: Please, comment on code, even if it's self explanatory.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.