# Spring Data JPA apply sorting, pagination along with a where clause

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am currently Using Spring JPA and utilizing the Sorting and Pagination as described here -

[How to query data via Spring data JPA by sort and pageable both out of box？](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527124/how-to-query-data-via-spring-data-jpa-by-sort-and-pageable-both-out-of-box)

Now my question is how do I apply a 'where' clause to this?

E.g.

```
where PRODUCT_NAME='abc';
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just create a query method in your repository interface for this.

Take a look in the docs, [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/1.0.0.M1/reference/html/#repositories.special-parameters).

Add a query method with paging and where clause.

```
Page<User> findByLastname(String lastname, Pageable pageable);
```

So you can find User by a property "lastname" and configure Paging settings.

Comment: Just a note: when using sorting and paging with Oracle database remember to put primary key of the table as the last sorting criteria. Otherwise pagination will be a total mess because of Oracle bug in query optimizer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16629702/7974082 . I've just wasted 3 hours of my life trying to fix broken paging.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way I could find is to [use QueryDSL or Specifications](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/). I prefer QueryDSL.

Comment: I prefer QueryDSL too,

Answer (score 0):

To fetch Spring Data JPA apply sorting, pagination along with a where clause check bellow codes

1. Entity class

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "users")
   Public Class User{
       private String name;
       private Integer id;
       private String email;
       // add required setter getter//
   }
   ```
2. Repository class

   ```
   @Repository("userRepository")
   @Transactional`
       public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer>{

       }
   ```
3. Service layer to pass where clause using Example object and Pagination+Sorting together using Pagable and Sort Class. We will implement Pageable in controller to inject Sorting logic then will pass that Pagable object to service Layer.

   ```
    @Service
    Public class UserService{
       public Page<User> getUserListPaginated(`EXAMPLE<User>` searchTerm, Pageable pageable) {
           return userRepo.findAll(searchTerm,pageable);
       }
   }
   ```

`Example<T>` does not take the attribute if its value is null. 
for that I used Integer id in Entity class as I can set it's value null for first call

4. Now Controller Class

   ```
   @Controller
   Public class UserController{

       @Autowired UserService userService;
       @GetMapping("/users")
       public String users(Model model,@RequestParam(value="page",defaultValue = "0") Integer  pageNumber, @SortDefault(sort = "name", direction = Sort.Direction.ASC) Sort sort){
           Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNumber,10, sort);
           Example<User> searchTerm = Example.of(new User());
           Page<User> userList = userService.getUserListPaginated(searchTerm, pageable);


       }
   }
   ```

Comment: The method findAll(Example<S>, Pageable) in the type QueryByExampleExecutor<User> is not applicable for the arguments (String, Pageable)..... I get this compilation error