# How to apply default sorting in Spring JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I'd like to provide a default pagination for my method using `Spring data jpa`.
How do I have to call the following method so that default pagination is applied?
I tried passing `null` argument but that would lead to an unpaged list.

```
interface PagedRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT u FROM user u WHERE)
    List<User> findAllPaged(@PageableDefault(size = 20));
}

//repo.findAllPaged(null);
```

I could pass a new Pageable myself, but that make `@PageableDefault` useless.
`repo.findAllPaged(new PageableRequest(0, 20));`

Comment: does this may be of some help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527124/how-to-query-data-via-spring-data-jpa-by-sort-and-pageable-both-out-of-box

Comment: this will help you brother http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-seven-pagination/

Comment: Please read the links you post before you answer. None of the links target my question "how can I use the method with @PageableDefault". As I wrote, I already know how I can pass a parameter as pageable.

Answer (score 1):

## Use Application.properties Configuration File

you can specify the default page size globally  in your configuration file with it be a yaml/toml or a properties file by setting your desired number like below :

> spring.data.web.pageable.default-page-size=**page-size**

Comment: Well but I would want to set different default sizes for different query methods. This would change the settings globally.

Comment: Well in that case, you have to add variables in your properties file and use `@Value` or `@ConfigurationPropertires` in every bean you want to inject these page sizes